# RMarkdown for docx: Text filled tables

Tags: r-markdown

I am creating an automated report for a client. The report needs to be in a Word document so that the client can make changes. The report needs to include a table like the one below:

[Picture of the table that I want](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TSTNb.png)

I don't know how to go about getting the table looking like this.

I have looked at the "styles" template as a possible solution to no avail.

Any guidance on getting this document looking how I want it to would be lovely.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

I solved my problem using the package flextable. It's a great way to get word tables (in any form